Struggling with OAuth in an Electron + React App – Need Guidance
I'm currently developing an Electron app using React and running into some trouble implementing OAuth. Here’s where I’m at:
I understand that I need to initiate the OAuth flow and handle the callback in Electron's main process.
My main process successfully handles the OAuth callback and retrieves the necessary tokens.
Now, the tricky part:
How do I best communicate the OAuth callback data (like tokens) from Electron's main process to the React renderer process?
Where and how should I handle these tokens on the React side to ensure proper state management and secure storage?
I’ve done some digging online but haven’t found many up-to-date examples or solid resources specific to this Electron + React combo. 
If you’ve tackled this before or have any pointers:
Can you share how you handled the callback flow?
Do you have recommendations for libraries or tools that can simplify this?
Are there any resources, articles, or examples you'd recommend for implementing OAuth in Electron apps?
Thanks in advance for any help! 
P.S. For context, I’m using the latest versions of Electron and React, and I’d prefer solutions that work with modern JavaScript/TypeScript practices.
